# drupal7 - automatic reload views when node changed

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal, drupal-7

I built a block of view in drupal 7 that display a nodes from a specific type in slideshow.

When something change in one of the nodes, data or publish/unpublished, I want to reload the view automatic with no click or reload.

I understand I can do it with ajax. I found few examples but in all I need to click on something and I need it with no human touch. How can I do it automatically?

I quite new with drupal and ajax.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Views Hack](https://drupal.org/project/views_hacks) module has an auto refresh sub-module that updates a view automatically when it's changed, without refreshing the view page.

You can also check the [Views content cache](https://drupal.org/project/views_content_cache) module, or the [Views Auto-Refresh](https://drupal.org/project/views_autorefresh) module. 
The Views Content Cache module provides caching for views until the content in it changes. The Views Auto-Refresh refreshes the view after a specified time interval.

Hope that helps.
B

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, finally I did it with jQuery.

I did:

In mymodule.js file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.location.href == "http://loc") {
    setInterval(check, 5000);
  }
  function check() {
    $ret = 0;
    jQuery.get("/path/to/check_slide", function( data ) {
      if(data == 1) {
        location.reload(); 
      } 
    }) 
  }
})
```

in drupal module I did:

In hook_init:

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . 'mymodule.js');
```

In hook_menu:

```
$items['/path/to/check_slide'] = array(
'page callback' => 'mymodule_check_slide', 
'access callback' => TRUE,
'type' => MENU_CALLBACK, );
```

In mymodule_check_slide :

```
    $ret = 0;

    if (variable_get('flag', 0)) {
        $ret = 1;
        variable_set('flag', 0);
    }

    print $ret;
    die();
}
```

In hook_node_presave:

```
if ($node -> type == 'slidetype') {
    variable_set('flag', 1);
}
```